# MinGW using g++ instead of c++ in command line?

Tags: c++, mingw

This is a fairly simple question, so i'll keep it simple.

I've just installed MinGW onto my windows. When i run the following:

```
c:/> c++ HelloWorld.cpp && a.exe
```

However in most tutorials and guides i see online, people will use

```
c:/> g++ HelloWorld.cpp
```

It seems to run the same, but i'm not quite sure what the difference is between c++ and g++. Is it a different compiler? a different language? does it run anything differently? Thanks`

Comment: Most likely they will be hardlinked to the same binary. You could inspect this by looking at `g++.exe` and `c++.exe` in your filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing. `g++` is just the executable (or link) name for then *GNU* C++ compiler. If you install MinGW, your `c++` executable (if present) will point to the GNU C++ compiler – since that is what you installed.